# How to copy Genshin Impact into another PC/Laptop?

Tags: pc, genshin-impact

I can't seem to find information online for how to copy a Genshin Impact installation to another computer. My internet speed is bad, so instead of downloading it again, I think it would be more feasible to copy the game from my PC to my laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if you copy the folder of Genshin impact to an external hard drive first then copy and paste it to your laptop. Steps below:

> 1.) Look for the folder where your Genshin Impact is installed
>
> 2.) Copy the whole folder and paste it to your external hard drive (provided it's connected to your PC)
>
> 3.) Paste to your laptop hard drive
>
> 4.) Create a shortcut for the Genshin Impact launcher
>
> 5.) Look for the config file inside the Genshin impact folder
>
> 6.) Change the location under game_install_path to where you saved it in the laptop (example C:/GAME/Genshin)
>
> 7.) Make sure to install [Microsoft visual C++ 2005](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)
> up to Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 at least
>
> 8.) Launch Genshin Impact and play

[Video Instructions here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7SkKKN9ROM)

Answer (score 1):

That simply can't be done, you can't move an installed game from a PC to another, you have to download it again and re-install it.

You can't copy/paste installed programs from the programs folder, as when a software/game is installed the files are spread throughout the operating system, in the registry and so on...

Comment: That's not true. You can very well copy most of the files from one PC to another. There are for sure some files missing, but any game that's being installed with a launcher or a repair option in the install process adds the missing files while not re-downloading/copying already existing files. Existing files can be files that were copied manually.

Comment: There are caveats, like Steam using Custom Executable Generation to effectively encrypt the executable for a game. I can't remember if those are replaced when it downloads with existing data or if they cause an issue, but regardless they can just be ignored when copying data to circumvent this.